# Set Spinner selection doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-spinner

I'm trying to set a spinner with setSelection in order to display a specific option as follows:

```
Spinner gender;
gender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_edit_gender);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.gender_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    gender.setAdapter(adapter);
    if (strGender.equals("male"))
        gender.setSelection(0,true);
    else
        gender.setSelection(1,true);
```

It always sets the first option of the spinner instead of what i want

Anyone know why and can help me plz?

Thanx

Comment: Where do you define `strGender`?

Comment: above the "Spinner gender;" i have String strGender and its value is "female", for sure.... i print it by Log

Comment: Just to make sure, `R.array.gender_array` does have two values, correct? Also, can you post the contents of it as well as your XML for `R.id.spinner_edit_gender`?

Comment: Ok, along with shanet's question about the contents of `gender_array`; know that `equals()` is case sensitive, verify that you are not trying to compare `"male"` and `"Male"`.

Comment: @Sam - If the `equals` test fails, then the second item should be selected. OP reports that the first item is always selected.

Comment: @TedHopp Understood, but this questions feels like a simple oops to me. I want to cover all of the basics, without assuming that the author isn't referring to index 1 as the first selection.

Comment: @shanet There are 2 options in the spinner, it is defined as:
<string name="gender">Gender</string>
 <string-array name="gender_array">
  <item>Male</item>
  <item>Female</item>
 </string-array>
The value is "female" and as Ted Hopp said, the second option should have been selected.

Comment: Thank you everybody!!! i solve the problem!!!!! i moved the code from its original place to another and it start working......

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setSelection(int)` instead of `setSelection(int, boolean)`.

Comment: I've always used `setSelection(int)` in my apps so I just tried changing to `setSelection(int, boolean)` in one instance with no noticeable difference. If this does end up being the solution to the OP's question, I'd love to know why.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to try:

1.) I'm going to take a shot in the dark here and suggest that you try defining the options to your spinner in it's XML. This is what I'm in one of my apps where I use `setSelection()` successfully.

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner_edit_gender"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
    android:prompt="@string/genders"
    android:entries="@array/gender_array"/>
```

and then your code becomes:

```
Spinner gender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_edit_gender);
if (strGender.equalsIgnoreCase("male"))
    gender.setSelection(0,true);
else
    gender.setSelection(1,true);
```

or if we want to get a little fancier:

```
Spinner gender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_edit_gender);
(strGender.equalsIgnoreCase("male")) ? gender.setSelection(0,true) : gender.setSelection(1,true);
```

I changed `equals()` to `equalsIgnoreCase()` because you the values in your array don't match the case of the values in your code in your example ("male" vs "Male").

2.) When I was typing the first part I noticed the type of your ArrayAdapter is `CharSequence`. Try changing that to `String` and then test your original code. However, depending on your needs, you might want to consider going with defining the options in XML because, at least in my opinion, it's a cleaner and simpler way of defining options for a spinner than dealing with ArrayAdapters.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, the first solution didn't work, and regarding to the second solution - I try to change to String but i got errors to change back to CharSequence....

Comment: Thank you everybody!!! i solve the problem!!!!! i moved the code from its original place to another and it start working......

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. For anyone that may come across this in the future, would you mind documenting where your code was originally, and where you moved it to that made it work?

Comment: the original place was in a function which takes data from DB, i moved it to "onResume()" itself